# ive split my access database and put back end on sql how do i distribute the front end to remote computers

Tags: sql, crm

Ive had a CRM made in Access 2010, we have 18 users and over 100,000 contacts which forced me to split the database although even when i split it it was far too slow over the network. Ive managed to have it recoded and have put the backend on Microsoft Express 2012 and it works perfectly fine on my computer which is also the server. However when i then place the front end on the remote computers it says it has an error connecting to the ODBC can anybody please help me as ive being doing this project for months put in a lot of work and no it seems this is my final hurdle

NB: the remote computers are running on Access Runtime.

Many Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your MS SQL Express database to accept remote connections. You can do this in the SQL Server Configuration Manager - I wrote a post about this a while ago, hope it helps:

http://ricardodsanchez.com/2012/04/05/how-to-configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/